# Calling same named functions from specific files in Bash

Tags: bash, function, shell, oop

If I have 3 sperate files each with functions of the same name:

```
# switch1.sh

switch()
{
    echo "SWITCH 1"
}

# switch2.sh

switch()
{
    echo "SWITCH 2"
}

# switch3.sh

switch()
{
    echo "SWITCH 3"
}
```

Is there a way to specify which function to call without making the fuction names unique?

Comment: No, there isn't. When you source each file, its function replaces the previous one.

Comment: Caveat: if you run the scripts normally (i.e. *not* with `source` or `.`), each one runs in a separate shell process, and therefore the function definitions are private to that script. But if you run them with `source` or `.`, @Barmar's description applies.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I assumed he was sourcing them, since otherwise you can't call them at all, so name conflicts aren't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar is right, "When you source each file, its function replaces the previous one."

For anyone, that's interested in the purpose of this question my goal was to get some sort of object oriented sanity in this bash script:

## switch1.sh

```
switch()
{
    echo "switch1"
}

check_administratorpassword()
{
    file="switch1.sh"
    description="Administrator password required to change system-wide preferences"
    switch=$(switch)

    if [ -n "$(security authorizationdb read system.preferences 2> /dev/null | grep -A1 shared | grep -E '(true|false)' | grep 'false')" ]; then 
        return 0
    else 
        return 1
    fi
}
```

## switch2.sh

```
switch()
{
    echo "switch2"

    if which brew > /dev/null; then
        read -p "Check for Homebrew updates? (y/n): " input
        if [[ $input == "Y" || $input == "y" ]]; then
            echo "Checking for Homebrew updates..."
            brew update
        elif [[ $input == "N" || $input == "n" ]]; then
            :
        else
            echo "Not a recognized input."
            switch_homebrewinstall
        fi
    else
        echo "Homebrew is not installed."
        read -p "Install Homebrew? (y/n): " input
        if [[ $input == "Y" || $input == "y" ]]; then
             # Install Homebrew, TODO: Find secure way to download homebrew
             echo -e "Installing Homebrew..."
            /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
        elif [[ $input == "N" || $input == "n" ]]; then
            :
        else
            echo "Not a recognized input."
            switch_homebrewinstall
        fi
    fi
    unset input
}

check_homebrewinstall()
{
    file="switch2.sh"
    description="Homebrew is installed."
    switch=$(switch)

    if which brew > /dev/null; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

## switch3.sh

```
switch()
{
    echo "switch3"
}

check_javainstall()
{
    file="switch3.sh"
    description="Java is installed."
    switch=$(switch)

    path=$(type -p java)
    if [[ $path = /dev/null ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
    unset path
}
```

## switch-test.sh

```
source switch1.sh
source switch2.sh
source switch3.sh

declare -a checkArray
checkArray[1]=check_administratorpassword
checkArray[2]=check_homebrewinstall
checkArray[3]=check_javainstall

for i in "${!checkArray[@]}"; do   
    ${checkArray[$i]}
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x97 ${description}"
    else
        echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x93 ${description}"
    fi
    source "${file}"
    switch
done
```

## Output

```
$ bash switch-test.sh
✗ Administrator password required to change system-wide preferences
switch1
✓ Homebrew is installed.
switch2
✓ Java is installed.
switch3
```

This file is re-source right before the switch function is called, giving a kind of funky illusion that its OOP. I wouldn't recommend doing this since no one looking at your code is going to assume that's what's going on, but its kinda cool.